# How to sort hash in ruby according to some custom rules

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array like this:

```
["Is", "Gandalf", "The", "Gray", "Insane"]
```

and I want to sort a hash according to the position of the key in the array. For example, I would like to sort:

```
{:count=>21, "Is"=>19, "Gandalf"=>1, "Gray"=>0, "Insane"=>1, "The"=>5}
```

into this:

```
{"Is"=>19, "Gandalf"=>1, "The"=>5, "Gray"=>0, "Insane"=>1, :count=>21}
```

Another example would be sorting this:

```
{:count=>3, "Is"=>11, "Insane"=>22, "Gray"=>0, "Gandalf"=>12, "The"=>2}
```

into this:

```
{"Is"=>11, "Gandalf"=>12, "The"=>2, "Gray"=>12, "Insane"=>22, :count=>3}
```

How would one do that?

Comment: Why are you sorting a hash? Hashes are random access data structures, so sorting the keys is purely cosmetic, with absolutely no value or improvement in access speed. In other words, it's a waste of time.

Comment: I'm not looking performance improvement, I'm looping trough the hash in the front end and doing something with each entry (entry is that hash from the question). I need it to be displayed in the same order every time

Comment: Explain what is happening on the front-end. As is, your request has code smell, and, if you're sending the data to a web front-end, use JSON to encode the data, send it to the browser, let JavaScript decode the JSON back to a hash, and access the resulting hash values there as normal.

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow, wouldn't my answer help? Whats the problem with that?

Comment: Why don't you just loop through the array instead of the hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Hash
  def sort_by_array a; Hash[sort_by{|k, _| a.index(k) || length}] end
end
```

will work for the first example:

```
a = ["Is", "Gandalf", "The", "Gray", "Insane"]

{:count=>21, "Is"=>19, "Gandalf"=>1, "Gray"=>0, "Insane"=>1, "The"=>5}.sort_by_array(a)
# => {"Is"=>19, "Gandalf"=>1, "The"=>5, "Gray"=>0, "Insane"=>1, :count=>21}
```

However, it will not work with your second example because the result you expect for the second one is not just sorting, but also requires changing the value for `"Gray"`:

```
{:count=>3, "Is"=>11, "Insane"=>22, "Gray"=>0, "Gandalf"=>12, "The"=>2}.sort_by_array(a)
# => {"Is"=>11, "Gandalf"=>12, "The"=>2, "Gray"=>0, "Insane"=>22, :count=>3}

# You wanted
# => {"Is"=>11, "Gandalf"=>12, "The"=>2, "Gray"=>12, "Insane"=>22, :count=>3}
```

Since it is not clear where the value `12` for `"Gray"` comes from, your question cannot be answered in a way that satisfies your second example.

Comment: Where does `class Hash def sort_by_array a; Hash[sort_by{|k, _| a.index(k) || length}] end end` go? I put it in the controller and it errors

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, convert it to an array, by populating the array in the order you require.
Then you can access the array itself by using that array or then converting that array to hashmap.

http://x3ro.de/ruby-19-array-hash/

One link discussing the similar lines is ,

[How to sort not simple hash (hash of hashes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362105/how-to-sort-not-simple-hash-hash-of-hashes)